# how to trigger a mouse_over event ONLY when mouse_down event is active?

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm building a game that relies on gaining points through having a `mouse_over` repeatedly over a hit area, but i want the player to only be able to gain points provided the `mouse_down` is active.  if i'm not getting syntax errors, nothing's happening. i know the code's wrong.

i need `hit` to make `pressing` true, and trigger `onPressing`, then,
`onPressing` to trigger `noot` as a `mouse_over`, and each mouse_over registers a score point and traces it.

```
var score:int = 0
score = 0;
var pressing:Boolean = false;

hit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, maketrue);
function maketrue(evt:Event){
pressing = true;
trace("honk");
onPressing();
}
}

function onPressing(evt:Event){
if (pressing==true){

noot();
}
}
function noot(event:MouseEvent = null)// this should be mouse_over, gain points
{
score++;
trace("Moused over");
trace("Score: " + score);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- There's an extra "}" after onPressing()
- onPressing() requires an argument - I suggest "evt"

Once these are fixed, the tracing will work, and the score in increment each time you click the hit symbol.

However, to achieve the effect you described where the user scores repeatedly for having the mouse over the hit area when the mouse button is down, I don't suggest using "Mouse Over". This is because Mouse Over will only trigger when the mouse is actually moving. When the user has rolled on top of the hit area and stopped, it will not fire the Mouse Over event.

I suggest the following adjustment:

```
var score:int = 0
score = 0;
var pressing:Boolean = false;

//stage listens for mouse down
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, maketrue);
function maketrue(evt:Event){
    pressing = true;
    trace("honk");
}

//stage listens for mouse up
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, makefalse);

function makefalse(evt:Event){
    pressing = false;
    trace("unhonk");
}

hit.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCollision);

function checkCollision(evt:Event):void{
    //pseudocode
    /*
    if(hitting cursor) && pressing){
        score++;
        trace("Score: " + score);
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have an event only when another even has been triggered you need a simple setup like this:

```
// In this example mouseOver event will only activate when mouseDown event has fired
// for the sake of simplicity this has been done in a frame, not in a class

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); // we'll use this as a button
mySprite.graphics.beginFill( 0xFF0000, 1);
mySprite.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 50 );
mySprite.graphics.endFill();
mySprite.x = 50;
mySprite.y = 50;
mySprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDownHandler);
addChild(mySprite);

var myMouseOverSprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); // this sprite will be used to roll over the mouse on
myMouseOverSprite.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1);
myMouseOverSprite.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 70 );
myMouseOverSprite.graphics.endFill();
myMouseOverSprite.x = 150;
myMouseOverSprite.y = 150;
addChild(myMouseOverSprite);


function onMouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("mouse is down on mySprite");
    myMouseOverSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouseRollOverHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUpHandler); // this is important so we don't have roll over firing after mouse is up
}

function onStageMouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myMouseOverSprite.graphics.clear();
    myMouseOverSprite.graphics.beginFill( 0x00FF00, 1); // return sprite to original color
    myMouseOverSprite.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 70 );
    myMouseOverSprite.graphics.endFill();
    myMouseOverSprite.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouseRollOverHandler);
}

function onMouseRollOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("mouse is rolling over myMouseOverSprite");
    myMouseOverSprite.graphics.clear();
    myMouseOverSprite.graphics.beginFill( Math.random() * int.MAX_VALUE >> 0, 1); // change sprite to a random color
    myMouseOverSprite.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 70 );
    myMouseOverSprite.graphics.endFill();
}
```

You will see two circles in this example. The red is a button - when you press down on it the green circle will be ready to receive the ROLL_OVER event. When you let the mouse go up again the green circle will return to it's starting state.